# Prepend or append PI before / after the root element with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, processing-instruction

With lxml, how can I prepend processing instructions before the root element or append PIs after de root element with lxml.

Currently, the following example doesn't work:

```py
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML("<ROOT/>")
root.addprevious(etree.ProcessingInstruction("foo"))
print(etree.tounicode(root))
```

I get:

```xml
<ROOT/>
```

Instead of:

```xml
<?foo?><ROOT/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ElementTree`, not just `Element` in `tounicode()`:

```py
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML("<ROOT/>")
root.addprevious(etree.ProcessingInstruction("foo"))
print(etree.tounicode(root.getroottree()))
```

Output is almost what you wanted:

```
<?foo ?><ROOT/>
```

Extra space character after `foo` showed up because `lxml` renders `PI` as `pi.target + " " + pi.text`.

Comment: I see people upvoting this answer, but the right answer is to use `etree.tounicode(root.getroottree())`: there is no need to create a new `ElementTree`. You may edit your answer so that I accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, an [`Element`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) is always attached to a [`ElementTree`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html) even if it looks "detached":

```py
root = etree.XML("<ROOT/>")
assert root.getroottree() is not None
```

When we use `addprevious`/`addnext` to insert a processing instruction before/after a root element, the PIs are not attached to a parent element (there isn't any) but they are attached to the root tree instead.

So, the problem lies in the usage of [`tounicode`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tounicode) (or `tostring`). The best practice is to print the XML of the root tree, not the root element.

```py
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML("<ROOT/>")
root.addprevious(etree.ProcessingInstruction("foo"))
root.addnext(etree.ProcessingInstruction("bar"))

print(etree.tounicode(root))
# => "<ROOT/>"

print(etree.tounicode(root.getroottree()))
# => "<?foo ?><ROOT/><?bar ?>"
```